# Visual Studio Code: Unable to open 'MyFile.h': File not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got this kind of errors when attempting to go to the declaration of some attributes/methods (using ctrl/cmd + left click):

> Unable to open 'MyFile.h': File not found

probably this happens because the file MyFile.h has been moved recently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by forcing VSCode to re-scan the project structure.

In order to do that, I closed VSCode, deleted the `.vscode` hidden folder of my project, and opened it again.

Comment: Just tried this fix, and wanted to report it still works.

Comment: Worked for me, but please remember to copy your tasks etc somewhere, as those things are not recreated

Comment: Actually, this only worked for about an  hour then I started seeing the issue again

Comment: it's probably some bug in Visual Studio Code

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and solved it by reloading my VS code window.

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` on Windows

`Command` + `Shift` + `P` on Mac

Type:

```
Reload Window
```

Then select `Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: At first this reload didn't helped in my case, but then i realised i had a server running in the background (with HMR) and after i turned it off, suddenly the reload helped as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior when browsing the file changes in the source control panel but for me the issue was that while I was reworking my project architecture, I had a remaining `.gitmodules` file in the root of my project, but the subdirectory was not a repository itself.

So I just deleted the `.gitmodules` file and it worked again.